# How to use Typescript Generics in modifier functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am looking for a way to correctly strong type a below case, I suspect i need to use Typescript Generics in this situation.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const person: Person = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30,
};

const alterPerson = (key: keyof Person, val) => {
  person[key] = val;
}
```

My intention is that function 'alterPerson' is aware it can only take Person keys as its first argument and then, once it has taken a key i want the function to know what type of value can be assigned to that key.

Can you show me how this could be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`alterPerson` is still directly coupled to the `person` variable. To make this truly reusable with generics, you'd need to also pass that variable as a function parameter.

```
const alterObject = <T>(object: T, key: keyof T, val: T[keyof T]) => {
  object[key] = val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution does seem to work! however I really wish there was a way not to pass that extra object argument. I will hold off marking this as correct just for a while in case an alternative is offered.

Comment: I don't think hard coding the object is a good idea, as it doesn't make the types of this function reusable so the generics don't really do much. Do you need to reuse this function, or did you just want to avoid using `Person` more than once in your original function?